# c# mapper object with one property from list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a request with Engine name, engine hp and list carid. How can i do map EngineTMP to EngineModelDto?

```
Table engine:
    id, name, hp, carid
    
    public class EngineModelDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Hp { get; set; }
        public Guid CarId { get; set;}
    }
    public class EngineTMP
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Hp { get; set; }
        public List<Guid> CarIds { get; set; }
    }
```

i want to do something similar like this pseudocode: (but with automapper)

```
List<EngineModelDto> myListDto = new List<EngineModelDto>();
for(int i = 0; i < CarIds.lenght - 1; i++)
    {
        var e = new EngineModelDto {
            Name = EngineTMP.name,
            Hp = EngineTMP.hp,
            CarId = EngineTMP.CarIds[i];
        }
    
        list.Add(e);
    }
```

Comment: there are different "mappers" available. I use Express mapper http://expressmapper.org/

Comment: I can map 1: 1  but i don't know how to do it with a list. I would like to have an EngineModelDto list containing the improved data based on EngineTMP

Comment: Do you want to create a dto for each id, or 1 dto with the first id?

Comment: for everyone carId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a simple mapping, you may be as well to do this manually:

```
var dtos = engineTmp.CarIds.Select(id => new EngineModelDto
{
    Name = engineTmp.Name,
    Hp = engineTmp.Hp,
    CarId = id,
});
```

However, if you insist on using AutoMapper, you could do something like this:

```
CreateMap<EngineTMP, IEnumerable<EngineModelDto>>()
    .ConvertUsing(src => src.CarIds?.Select(id => new EngineModelDto
    {
        Name = src.Name,
        Hp = src.Hp,
        CarId = id,
    }));
```

Then:

```
var dtos = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EngineModelDto>>(engineTmp);
```